# In Windows OS, sysdm.cpl what dm stands for?

Tags: windows, command

In Windows OS, command sysdm.cpl refers to  System Applet for the Control Panel , what dm stands for ? or is there a mnemonic to remember the command?

Answer (score 4):

DM stands for **Device Manager** it seems(reference - https://superuser.com/questions/1115076/what-does-the-dm-in-sysdm-cpl-stand-for)

I know, it was answered late ;)

but just now I came across this question. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like, `sysdm.cpl` stands for ***SYS***tem **D**evice **M**anager **C**ontrol **P**ane**L** applet: , in a *hungarian notation*-ish form.

From that executable (now called `SystemPropertiesComputerName.exe`) you can now change all sorts of system properties, also back on windows 95 you could affect more than the simple device management tab.

However, if you edit the original file from windows 95, you can find a reference to that *System Setting Device Manager Control Panel Applet*.

Here the screenshot from the first version of the applet that i could find, on Windows 95 First Retail Release:

[image: sysdm.cpl file contain correct reference]

Note: Previously I was wrong based on the file description alone:
[image: sysdm.cpl properties windows 95 First Retail Release]

**UPDATE** after 5 years I saw other answers and I decided to update my originally wrong answer with the correct one, backed up with some research.